# SpriteBatch DrawString is Drawing the wrong Charracter

Tags: monogame, drawstring, spritebatch

I have been working on an app for practicing and learning Japanese, for that reason I use characters outside of the English alphabet. I have recently updated the work I had done on the app moving it to a new solution to take advantage of the newer pipeline process. I have the fundamentals of the app working, but when I display the Japanese characters a blank box is drawn there instead...

I cant post a picture of this due to being new...

This is strange because when the code was in the previous solution it did not do this. In the previous solution i used a separate project for the content of the app. I have tried changing the font to see if there was something wrong there, but no luck.

Is there a common problem I'm missing? I assume that this means that the method is returning a null somewhere, but then I don't know why it worked before...

I have check under the Fonts "Characters" property and found that the font has the character that i am trying to use at the time, so the error must happen sometime after that.

```
static private void DrawStat(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, int current)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(CharracterFont, TempList[current].ReadCharracter.readChar, new Vector2(DrawArea.X, DrawArea.Y + 20 + (50 * (current - Selected))), Color.Black, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 0.1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(EnglishFont, TempList[current].ReadCharracter.ReadSound, new Vector2(DrawArea.X + 100, DrawArea.Y + 20 + (50 * (current - Selected))), Color.Black, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 0.2f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(EnglishFont, TempList[current].readAccuracies.X.ToString(), new Vector2(DrawArea.X + 200, DrawArea.Y + 20 + (50 * (current - Selected))), Color.Black, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 0.2f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(EnglishFont, TempList[current].readAccuracies.Y.ToString(), new Vector2(DrawArea.X + 300, DrawArea.Y + 20 + (50 * (current - Selected))), Color.Black, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 0.2f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
    }
```

Sorry for the messy code...

I am wondering if there is a problem between coping the spritefont over from the other solution, but i did the same for the English font and got no problem...

Comment: Found it was a problem with the monogame spritefont importer

 So I looked and found that the spriteFonts are imported by a new importer. I put a stop point in my program before it loaded the font and swaped the Font xnb generated by the monogame importer for one made by the Xna one, this seem to solve the problem i was having.

Answer (score 0):

Found it was a problem with the monogame spritefont importer So I looked and found that the spriteFonts are imported by a new importer. I put a stop point in my program before it loaded the font and swaped the Font xnb generated by the monogame importer for one made by the Xna one, this seem to solve the problem i was having.